# Angular component uses multiple services from different modules

Tags: angular, service, components

I am having a bit of a hard time finding a good solution for the following problem (if it is a problem).

I have for example an application with different modules for let's say: owners, locations and cars.

Now I am building a 'search' component which can search for a car. The logic for searching a car is in the car.service of the car module.

But when a car is found I also have to set a location so the location.service from the location module is also used in the search component to find a location based on a given ID.

So now I have a search component which needs both the location.service and car.service.

This feels a bit like a bad practice? Are there any solutions for this kind of problems. Or is this common for Angular components and services?

Comment: I won't say it bad to have a searchComponent that needs the location and car service. Setting the location (state) in the locationService is fine for small projects. When you project is getting bigger you might consider using a state management library like ngrx or ngxs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your components are supposed to handle the logic of your view. This means that they should handle button clicks, forms, and so on.

When you have business logic, you should use a service. In your case, you did well, creating 3 services for each "class" of your data model.

Now, what you missed is that you don't need 2 dependencies in your component : you only need one.

You've built a car's search component → you need a dependency to your car service. That's all.

What you will do is call the service, search for your car, and **in your service**, set the location (meaning your car service has a dependency to location).

The logic behind that is simple : imagine that tommorow, you also want to notify the seller that someone looked up for their car. What will you do ? Will you add a third dependency to your component ?

No. What you will do is leave the component as it already is, and add a dependency to your service.

Now, the next day, you decide to switch from Firebase to Parse, because it's free. What happens in your case ? You have to change your component dependencies ?

In my case, your component is left untouched. Only your car service will change its dependency from firebase to parse. Because the component doesn't care about which provider you're using, it just wants to search for a car.

This way of doing things allow you to create component and services that you can reuse, either in the same application, or other applications.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly. When the search is done in the car.service I can call the location.service in the car.service to search for the correct location and set it? :)

Comment: Exactly. It's up to your car service to call location service, not the component !

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbie in Angular. I think it's normal when you import service from other module. But, in my project, I create a folder name `_services` where I store all services of my project. Next, I create a file name `index.ts` :

```
export * from './authencation.service';
export * from './alert.service';
export * from './notebook.service';
```

And when i need import service, i call `import { StatisticSerivce, AlertService, UserService } from '../../../_services/index';`